# ComboBox binding - SelectedItem lost after ViewModel change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

## The situation

### Main Window and ContentControl

I have a MainWindow with a HamburgerMenu at the left. The DataContext of MainWindow is MainViewModel.

Therein are commands defined to switch between the ViewModels of the 'child views' which are displayed in the center area of MainWindow using a ContentControl. The commands are bound to the HamburgerMenu to perform the view model switching. They are defined inside the constructor of MainViewModel like this:

```
CmdOpenMethodView = new RelayCommand(p =>
{
  if (MethodVM == null)
  {
    MethodVM = new MethodViewModel();
  }

  CurrentViewModel = MethodVM;

}, p => !(CurrentViewModel is MethodViewModel));

CmdOpenSettingsView = new RelayCommand(p =>
{
  if (SettingsVM == null)
  {
    SettingsVM = new SettingsViewModel();
  }

  CurrentViewModel = SettingsVM;

}, p => !(CurrentViewModel is SettingsViewModel));
```

The ContentControl is bound to property CurrentViewModel (of type BaseViewModel) which is defined in MainViewModel.

The MainWindow.xaml (without header) goes like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu Grid.Column="0"
                               Background="#6080bc" 
                               MenuIconColor="White"
                               SelectionIndicatorColor="White" 
                               MenuItemForeground="White" 
                               MaxWidth="130"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem Text="Method" 
                                     SelectionCommand="{Binding CmdOpenMethodView}"/>

    <HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem Text="Settings" 
                                     SelectionCommand="{Binding CmdOpenSettingsView}"/>
  </HamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu>
  <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The connection between the child view <-> view models is set up in App.xaml as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <!--Wire the view models and views-->
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MethodViewModel}">
    <Views:MethodView />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SettingsViewModel}">
    <Views:SettingsView />
  </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

### Child controls

So, the center area of MainWindow displays either MethodView or SettingsView.

MethodsView contains a ComboBox which is bound to a property 'CurrentMethod' of MethodViewModel like this:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMethod, 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllMethodsView}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding IsMenuAllowed}"
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

The ItemsSource is set to MethodViewModel.AllMethodsView which is of type ListCollectionView. The SelectedItem is bound to MethodViewModel.CurrentMethod of my custom type Method.

## The problem

When clicking in the MainMenu/HamburgerMenu to open the settings view, the settings view opens.

When then clicking to open the methods view again, the methods view opens but the combobox has forgotten its selected item.

In debugging MethodViewModel I see the ListCollectionView.CurrentItem is set to null when the ContentView switches to display SettingsView.

How can I prevent this?

**Edit:** 
I added an example to [GitHub](https://github.com/rosneru/ChangeViewsMVVM) to provide a demonstration app.

Not sure if it builds out of the box, but the source is there, and maybe somebody has an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible sample app? Why are you using `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`?

Comment: I think to diagnose the problem we would need to see the navigation commands (`CmdOpenMethodView` and/or `CmdOpenSettingsView`)

Comment: I suspect that your content control is loading a new instance of the view-view model each time you switch between views. If so, it is no surprise your selected item is null. I'd like to have a look at the `CmdOpenMethodView` and `CmdOpenSettingsView` commands if you don't mind.

Comment: I've added the requested commands to the question.

Comment: @phibel Your datacontext is `CurrentViewModel`, you switch this on the fly so this means your combobox loses its datacontext, it's reconnected later but its value was already changed to `null` while it had no datacontext

Comment: @EpicKip This I suspected, too. Do you maybe know a workaround, maybe an additional binding property for the combobox? Or do I have to change the design of the app?

Comment: @phibel It would depend on your needs, if you only need to know what the selected combobox item is you could make the binding onewaytosource, another thing that might work is using notify property changed with value null, this will notify about every property and it might restore the selected item from the datacontext once you connect it back.

Comment: @mm8 I uploaded an example app to GitHub, see the last part of the question.